# How to send messages to the private MessageQueue on remote computer in different domain than client computer?

Tags: c#, .net, message-queue

I want to send Messages to the **private** `MessageQueue`on our server which is in different domain. How can I do it?

When I send messages to the same queue from other computer in the "same" domain, I get the messages as expected. But when I try to send them from computer in some other domain, I neither get messages in the `MessageQueue` nor do they remain in the OutgoingQueues on client machine. They are lost ! 
I can see `count` of the messages in the `OutgoingQueues` on client. Also `OutgoingQueue` says that the messages were `Unacknowledged`.

I have already tried using both the IP address of the remote machine and the full computer name too. e.g. remoteMachineName.otherDomainName.companyName.com

Answer (score 1):

The messages are lost because you are not asking MSMQ to keep them when an error occurs.
You need to add Negative Source Journaling to your code to ensure such messages are not discarded but moved to the Dead Letter Queue on the sender instead.

When you say "different domain" do you mean "different forest"? The distinction is important as domains in different forests do not share a common security database.

Problem is likely to be queue permissions - you need to add Anonymous Logon if the sender is in a different forest.

[Cross-forest MSMQ? You need to be trusting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/06/27/cross-forest-msmq-you-need-to-be-trusting.aspx)

["How do I send MSMQ messages between domains?"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/02/14/how-do-i-send-msmq-messages-between-domains.aspx)

Cheers

John Breakwell

Comment: +1 for providing so valuable reference material. Domains are in the same forest. Any idea why would there be a problem in the same forest?